# Comparing Ranks of Free Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, free-modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M$ and $N$ be a free module module over $R$.　The the rank(may infinite) of $M$ and $N$ are determined uniquely.

If there is a injection $M$ to $N$ ,then the cardinal of $rank(M)$ is equal to or less than the cardinal of $rank(N)$?

1,If $rank(N)$ is finite, I know the well-known proofs (using matrix or exterior algebra).
2,If $R$ is domain, it's so easy ( tensorig the quotient ring. If $R$ is a field ,the problem is just a problem for (finite-dim or infinite-dim) vector spaces)

I can't prove if $rank(N)$ is infinite.

(Sorry for my poor English)

I think "the proof " would use Zorn's lemma...

Or are there some counter-example?

Comment: My "idea" of the proof is as following.

let {$u_i | i \in I$} be the base of $M$ and {$v_j | j \in J$} be the base of $N$.
I want to construct a injection from $I$ to $J$.

Let consider $A$ to be a set of $(K,\phi)$　where $K$　is a subset of $I$ and injection $\phi : K \to J$　and satisfies some "good conditions".

Comment: $A$ is a inductive ordered set so it has a maximal element $(K,\phi)$ and {$u_k | i \in K$} generates $M$. Then $\sum_{k\in K} Ru_k$ and $\sum_{i\in I} Ru_i$ are isomorpthic ,so the cardinal of $K$ and $I$ are equal and $card(I)=card(K) \leq card(J)$...

To satisfy the property " {$u_k | i \in K$} generates $M$....", I must set "good condition" and show it's existence (using the case of finite rank?),I think...